# Tensorflow time-series classification using parquet files

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, parquet, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am currently receiving one of the following errors (depending on the sequence of data prep):

`TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._NestedVariant object at 0x000001E02F62FB00>`

`TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <_VariantDataset shapes: OrderedDict`

Background: I have some parquet files, where each file is a multi-variate time-series. Since I am using the files for a multivariate time-series classification problem, I am storing the labels in a single numpy array. I need to use `tf.data.Dataset` for reading the files, since I cannot fit them all in memory.

Here is a working example that reproduces my error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Masking, LSTM, Dropout, Dense
#!pip install tensorflow-io
import tensorflow_io as tfio


num_files = 10
num_features = 3
num_timesteps = 50
num_classes = 2

batch_size = 2

for i in range(num_files):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.rand(num_timesteps), "B": np.random.rand(num_timesteps), "C": np.random.rand(num_timesteps)})
    df.to_parquet("file_{}.parquet".format(i))
    
columns_init = {"A": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32), "B": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32), "C": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32)}
    
labels = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

train_split_size = 0.8
num_train_files = int(train_split_size * num_files)

train_names = ["file_{}.parquet".format(i) for i in range(num_train_files)]
val_names = ["file_{}.parquet".format(i) for i in range(num_train_files, num_files)]

y_train = labels[ : num_train_files]
y_val = labels[num_train_files : num_files]

def map_fn(file_names, label_ds):
    return tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(file_names, columns=columns_init), label_ds

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_names, y_train))
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size = num_train_files)
train_ds = train_ds.map(map_fn)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(batch_size)

val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_names, y_val))
# No need for shuffling the validation set
val_ds = val_ds.map(map_fn)
val_ds = val_ds.batch(batch_size)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(batch_size)

ip = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, num_features))
x = Masking()(ip)
x = LSTM(8)(x)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(ip, out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds)
```

How do I overcome this error? I would prefer to keep my files separate and shuffle only how they are batched, since I don't want to meddle with the time-series sequences within the files. Is there a similar solution for `.csv` files instead of `.parquet`. I prefer parquet files because they are lighter and easier to read, but I am happy to convert my files if there is no turnaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue, I found a workaround, which was not straightforward. In this case, I defined a `common_ds` function for reading all the data from the files. I applied batching, where the batch size is equal to the time-series length to split the observations as they were stored. (Note: this assumes that the files are already preprocessed and all the files have equal number of rows.) After combining the features with the labels, the data is shuffled and batched according to the desired batch size. The final step uses the `pack_features_function` to change the format into tensor shapes that can be fed to the model.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Masking, LSTM, Dropout, Dense, Input
#!pip install tensorflow-io
import tensorflow_io as tfio

num_files = 10
num_features = 3
num_timesteps = 50
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 2

for i in range(num_files):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.rand(num_timesteps),
                       "B": np.random.rand(num_timesteps), 
                       "C": np.random.rand(num_timesteps)})
    df.to_parquet("file_{}.parquet".format(i))
    
columns_init = {"A": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32), 
                "B": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32),
                "C": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.float32)}
    
labels = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

train_split_size = 0.8
num_train_files = int(train_split_size * num_files)

train_names = ["file_{}.parquet".format(i) for i in range(num_train_files)]
val_names = ["file_{}.parquet".format(i) for i in range(num_train_files, num_files)]

y_train = labels[ : num_train_files]
y_val = labels[num_train_files : num_files]

def make_common_ds(files):
    common_ds = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(files[0], columns=columns_init)
    for file_name in files[1:]:
        ds = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(file_name, columns=columns_init)
        common_ds = common_ds.concatenate(ds)
    return common_ds

def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
    """Pack the features into a single array."""
    features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=2)
    return features, labels

train_names_ds = make_common_ds(train_names)
train_names_ds = train_names_ds.batch(num_timesteps)
train_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train)
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_names_ds, train_label_ds))
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size = num_train_files)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(batch_size)
train_ds = train_ds.map(pack_features_vector)

val_names_ds = make_common_ds(val_names)
val_names_ds = val_names_ds.batch(num_timesteps)
val_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_val)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((val_names_ds, val_label_ds))
# No need to shuffle the validation set
val_ds = val_ds.batch(batch_size)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(batch_size)
val_ds = val_ds.map(pack_features_vector)

ip = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, num_features))
x = Masking()(ip)
x = LSTM(8)(x)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(ip, out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds)
```